# Golang UDP Server only recieving locally sent packets

Tags: linux, go, network-programming, udp

I've written a UDP Server in Go(listens on port 666), and it seems to be only receiving packets that were sent locally. To confirm traffic, I have been using:

```
sudo tcpdump -n udp dst port 666
```

My(abbreviated) server code:

```
import "net"

func startServer() {
    // Bind the port.
    ServerAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "localhost:666")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error binding port!")
    }

    ServerConn, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", ServerAddr)
    defer ServerConn.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        // Recieve a UDP packet and unmarshal it into a protobuf.
        n, _, _ := ServerConn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
        fmt.Println("Packet received!")
        // Do stuff with buf.
    }
}
```

If, from the machine the server is running on, I use:

```
echo -n “foo” | nc -4u -w1 127.0.0.1 666
```

then the server receives that packet, and prints the message(and tcpdump shows no output).

However, if I run the following from another computer on the network:

```
echo -n “foo” | nc -4u -w1 192.168.1.134 666
```

Then, while tcpdump reports a packet being received (`15:05:43.634604 IP 192.168.1.113.59832 > 192.168.1.134.666: UDP, length 9` confirming I got the IP address right), the Go server does not respond.

Is there something special I need to do to make Go respond to non-local requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just listen on any address, you're listening on localhost only.

```
ServerAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":666")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doing what you told it to do: listen at 127.0.0.1. If you want it to listen at all interfaces, you have to specify 0.0.0.0.

Don't ask me how that's done in Go.

Comment: Yep. Wow, that was a big hole in my understanding of IP. Thanks!